# Cannot generate APN SSL certificate for push

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, push-notification, apns-php

I have been trying to generate the `APN SSL` certificate for days. After I select the certificate request in the file browser and press the "Generate" button in the developer portal. Nothing happens. There is no errors and no messages. It just hangs there like nothing has happened. My app is already running on the app store I need it to support push on the next version.

Comment: Hello , It can be a problem related to browser, which browser are you using?

Comment: I am have tried safari and firefox

Comment: Have you managed to generate it? I'm encountering the same issue. Tried on Safari and Google Chrome.

Comment: i was able to get around by doing it on another computer, seems like apple's keychain service is doing something weird there.

Comment: It worked for me on Safari!